# Send information with UIButton to void method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am creating a large set of buttons with a for loop and would like to send data from a set when the button is clicked

My button is in a for loop like so

The title is being processed in a for loop while the Url is a dictionary for the key of the title

```
-(void)addToScrollView {

     UIColor *ezBlue = [UIColor colorWithRed:(17.0 / 255.0) green:(95.0 / 255.0) blue:(207.0 / 255.0) alpha: 1];
    UIColor *ezGreen = [UIColor colorWithRed:(57.0 / 255.0) green:(145.0 / 255.0) blue:(2.0 / 255.0) alpha: 1];


    yLoc = 0;
    for(NSString *titleString in titlesArray) {

        int bufferInt = 2;
        buttonHeight = 0;
        buttonTop = yLoc;

        NSString *descString = [dFT objectForKey:titleString];
        NSString *dispUrlString = [duFT objectForKey:titleString];
        NSString *urlString = [uFT objectForKey:titleString];

        ...
        ...

        UIButton *buttonToPage = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, buttonTop, 280, buttonHeight)];
        [buttonToPage addTarget:self action:@selector(customBrowser:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [mainScrollView addSubview:buttonToPage];

    }
    height = yLoc;
    [self scrollViewHeight];
}
```

and the void method the data should be sent to

```
-(void)customBrowser:(NSString *)url {
//Do Stuff here
}
```

How do I pass information such as the url to the void method so it can be processed.

Comment: You didn't specify how the URL is related to the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up setting the button's title as the url and reading it in the method like so..

Setting it...

```
UIButton *buttonToPage = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, buttonTop, 280, buttonHeight)];
        [buttonToPage setTitle:urlString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buttonToPage addTarget:self action:@selector(customBrowser:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [mainScrollView addSubview:buttonToPage];
```

Reading it...

```
-(void)customBrowser:(UIButton *)sender {
//Do Stuff here
NSLog(@"The button title is %@",sender.titleLabel.text);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have an array with URLs or something like that, right?

this is not the best way to do it, but you can use the "tag" property in the button to indicate the index of your URL.

```
-(void)customBrowser:(UIButton *)sender
{
   NSString *stringURL = self.arrayURL[sender.tag];
   //do your stuff here
}
```

But, I will recommend you to try using TableViews or CollectionViews to solve your issue.